# Why is absolute value of INT_MIN different from INT MAX?

Tags: c++, c, types, int

I'm trying to understand why `INT_MIN` is equal to `-2^31 - 1` and not just `-2^31`.

My understanding is that an `int` is `4 bytes = 32 bits`. Of these `32 bits`, I assume `1 bit` is used for the +/- sign, leaving `31 bits` for the actual value. As such, `INT_MAX` is equal to `2^31-1 = 2147483647`. On the other hand, why is `INT_MIN` equal to `-2^31 = -2147483648`? Wouldn't this exceed the '4 bytes' allotted for `int`? Based on my logic, I would have expected `INT_MIN` to equal `-2^31 = -2147483647`

Comment: there are `2^32` possible ways you can set 32 bits. If you don't want to waste any of them, then that's a range with an even number of elements in it.  However a range of -X through to X (for some number X) has an odd number of elements.

Comment: The system you describe (which is called *sign-magnitude*) wastes the case of sign-bit 1 and all other bits 0 . In the past, some computers used this system anyway, but it is rare nowdays.

Comment: What you're describing is a [sign-and-magnitude number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation). That works okay, but means you can have `+0` and `-0`. So pretty much all computers use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement), because there's only one `0` (it's neither positive nor negative; just zero), and it has some convenient implications when it comes to binary arithmetic.

Comment: OP has it the wrong way around. INT_MAX is 2^31-1, INT_MIN is -2^31. It's because there is only one zero, not a +0 and a -0 like in ones-complement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most modern systems use [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent signed integer data types. In this representation, one state in the positive side is used up to represent zero, hence one positive value lesser than the negatives. In fact this is one of the prime advantage this system has over the [sign-magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign-and-magnitude) system, where zero has two representations, +0 and -0. Since zero has only one representation in two's complement, the other state, now free, is used to represent one more number.

Let's take a small data type, say 4 bits wide, to understand this better. The number of possible states with this toy integer type would be 2⁴ = 16 states. When using two's complement to represent signed numbers, we would have 8 negative and 7 positive numbers and zero; in sign-magnitude system, we'd get two zeros, 7 positive and 7 negative numbers.

```
Bin    Dec
0000 = 0
0001 = 1
0010 = 2
0011 = 3
0100 = 4
0101 = 5
0110 = 6
0111 = 7
1000 = -8
1001 = -7
1010 = -6
1011 = -5
1100 = -4
1101 = -3
1110 = -2
1111 = -1
```

I think you are confused since you are imagining that sign-magnitude representation is used for signed numbers; although this is also allowed by the language standards, this system is very less likely to be implemented as two's complement system is significantly a better representation.

As of C++20, only two's complement is allowed for signed integers; [source](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2131r0.html#removed).